# Geth version 1.14.4-stable Error: authentication needed: password or unlock. Transfer issue?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, wallets, private-blockchain, geth-debugging

I want to make a transfer between two wallets; one is the address I set up on my private blockchain, and the other is my Metamask address. However, I keep encountering the same error. I have attached a screenshot of the error. When I looked at previous solutions, I couldn't solve it because the personal.unlock structure has been removed. What is the current solution method used?[image]